# onEdit Google Sheet script runs only on one sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's the code I've got. It's not working and I'm not sure why!I want this script to run only on the tab/sheet called Trading Journal. Currently nothing happens when I include the if statement.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var cell = e.range;
   
     var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();  
  if(sh.getName() === "Trading Journal") {

  // set active cell colour
  cell.setBackground('#fff');
  cell.setFontSize(10)      // Sets size to 10 (has to be a number)
  cell.setFontFamily()      // Resets font family 
}
}
```

Thanks ahead of time for the help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PNRiKlCJJxVKxUBq26wlCrnAEHbXxEkTB6dC_QGBb2k/edit#gid=2146170730

Comment: I just open your spreadsheet and it works as intended. I see no problem. Background sets in white when I edit any cell on the sheet 'Trading Journal'. And it does nothing on another sheet.

Comment: It doesn't resets the font family, though. You should add font name of 'undefined' in the brackets if you want to change a font.

Comment: Vote to close since there is no feedback and the problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

This will execute on any edit on sheet Trading Journal

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Trading Journal') {
    e.range.setBackground('#ffffff');
    e.range.setFontSize(10);      
    e.range.setFontFamily("Arial");      
  })
}
```